# reading 7 variables (1 line per variable) from a file and assigning to struct variables

Tags: c, file, input, struct, stream

I'm making a simple enrollment system that maintains a database of a collection of computer science students. Each student record contains

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct student
{

   char name[300];   
   int age;
   char course_1[40];
   char course_2[40];
   char *remarks;

};

struct course

{

   char course_title[200];
   int  cse_num[100];
   char instructor[200];
   char date[50];
   char start_time[50];
   char end_time[50];
   char location[50];

};


main()

{

  int i;
  struct course data[11];
  FILE *f;
  char title[100];
  int num[100];
  char instructor[100];
  char date[100];
  char start_time[100];
  char end_time[100];
  char location[100];
  char line[300];

  f = fopen("course.dat", "r");


  i=0;


  while(*fgets(line, 300, f) != '\n')

  {
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", num);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", title);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", instructor);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", date);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", start_time);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", end_time);
      sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", location);

      data[i].cse_num = num // doesn't work

      strcpy(data[i].course_title, title);
      strcpy(data[i].instructor, instructor);
      strcpy(data[i].date, date);
      strcpy(data[i].start_time, start_time);
      strcpy(data[i].end_time, end_time);
      strcpy(data[i].location, location);


      i++;


  }

  fclose(f);


}
```

***My question is how to take in the input from the file since it is 7 lines until a new line is considered. I tried my best to explain this, thanks if you can try to help me guys!! I really focused on this just couldn't figure it out to be honest. This is the file:***

Example input:

```
CSE1001
Research Directions in Computing
Wildes, Richard
W
16:30
17:30
VC 135
```

Comment: I am suggesting re-tagging your Question to c

Comment: 1. The code you provided doesn't look like C# 2. Horrendous formatting (please use the orange question mark when you're posting to learn how to format) of  3. Enormous text wall. Do not post an entire program, do not post an entire file. Post relevant code and a succinct example of your input. 4. You haven't tried this problem yourself yet either

Comment: Your code likes c, but you taged it with c#. What language ate you talking about?

Comment: Sorry guys It's in C... just new to this site.

Comment: Since your new to this site: @tnw's comment is entirely in place and is meant to guide you as an obviously new user.

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry @tnw

Comment: @tnw I did try the problem, I was working on it for already 2 days. This isn't the whole program but this is just the only problem I have with the program... I can't understand how to take 7 inputs from a file and set it to my struct for some reason I always get infinite loops

Comment: @geforce It's alright. Most people are here to help, don't immediately get so defensive. Okay, go ahead and include the code you've attempted in the while loop. It would be useful to see that, in addition to the context to the problem, which is an infinite loop you're running into. Also, in the future, only include relevant code. includes, class declarations, and class members don't seem relevant to the problem. It makes your question much more readable. Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. You said that there were in your example input file there *are* newlines after each of the valid inputs. So you're saying you want to read 7 items into 7 variables?

Comment: @Mike yeah someone edited it, those 7 inputs you see is treated as 1 COURSE.. i.e there is more than one course so theres a new line and then more courses with the course_title, course_num etc etc

Comment: I think the main problem is my sscanf, I'm using the wrong input reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget, you must also `strcpy(data[i].course_title, title);`

and that goes for all strings.

You are currently doing this: `data[i].course_title = title;`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was trying to figure out why it was giving me an error earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the use of [scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scanf/info).  It's a general use function for parsing input from the terminal or from a file with the `fscanf` variant. It's already a part of the libraries you'd be including, and is similar in formatting to `printf` which you'll use lots for program output.

Comment: For the multi-word strings (job title, etc), `fgets()` is probably better, though the newline will need to be clipped from the string before assignment to the structure via `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You've misdeclared `main()`:

```
struct course
{
    char course_title[200];
    int  cse_num[100];
    char instructor[200];
    char date[50];
    char start_time[50];
    char end_time[50];
    char location[50];
}

main()
{
```

This says that `main()` returns a `struct course`.  That's wrong.

1. Add a semi-colon after the structure.
2. Always provide an explicit type for every function.  C99 requires it; it is good practice for C89.

The code should start:

```
struct course
{
    char course_title[200];
    int  cse_num[100];
    char instructor[200];
    char date[50];
    char start_time[50];
    char end_time[50];
    char location[50];
};

int main(void)
{
```

You should be getting warnings from your C compiler about this mistake.  If you weren't, you either need to turn warnings on or you need to get a better compiler.

This may or may not be directly related to the other problems you face, but it should be fixed.

Comment: Hi, I set that earlier.. due to me being new to this forum it screwed up.

Comment: Note that `sscanf(line, "%s", title);` only reads the word 'Research' of 'Research Directions in Computing' into the title.  You need to trim the newline off `line` and copy that to the `title` in the structure.  Similarly for the instructor name.  (Or you can use `sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", title)`, which reads up to a newline, and only 99 characters worth — avoiding buffer overflows.)  You could read direct into the structure, avoiding a layer of copying: `sscanf(line, "%99[^\n]", data[i].course_title);`.  You should also check that the `sscanf()` operations succeed, every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonathan, I'm going to try this now.